# Copy data from one sheet to another depending on Text in the cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have an sheet Data. In column J of data I look for the text "delayed".

If it contains this text delayed, then I copy the complete row to another sheet"Delayed".

The Problem here while copying is the column is entered manully, and in some cases the sapce and cases of letters varies.

So, I would like to know, is there a way, Irrespective of text case, and the gaps, I can copy the complete row to next sheet.

I have the below code, to check if it is delayed and copy data to the sheet "Delayed". Any lead with this would be helpful

```
Sub delay()
Dim cell1 As Range
Dim nextrow1 As Long
Dim a1 As Double

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
a1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Data").Range("J:J"))
For Each cell1 In Sheets("Data").Range("J5:J" & a1)
If cell1.Value = "delayed  " Then
nextrow1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Delayed").Range("J:J"))
Rows(cell1.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Delayed").Range("A" & nextrow + 1)
End If

Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Comment: reasding your profile you don't seem to accept answers 1 out of 10 = 10%.  Not bothering with you.

Comment: If i am not wrong, accepting answers means, giving it a green tick am I right ?

Comment: that's it.  You can upvote as well to give a full 25 points to answerer.  Cheers.

Comment: I am doing it , when the solution I am getting from the experts are working with my case .

Comment: @pnuts I will look into my profie and will resolve it